# Convert newline character to "\n" string

Tags: c#, string, newline

This is probably a silly question but some cursory searches haven't given me an answer. I have a problem where I am looking for invalid characters in a string; among them happen to be newline characters, tab characters, and the like. However, when one is found, it prints out to a console; as you can imagine,

```
"Character 
 is invalid"
```

might confuse the team at a glance. So is there a quick and easy way in C# to convert a newline character to its string literal version, `"\n"`, but will *not* convert invalid characters that are not 'special'?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions
class Foo {
    Regex invalidCheck = @"[^\w_ ]";

    public void ParseString(string command) {
        var invalid = invalidCheck.Match(command)
        if (invalid.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid character " + invalid.Value)
        else {
            // Do things with the string...
        }
    }
}
```

When the program is running, I don't know what `invalid.Value` *actually is*, but I know I need to get it to convert whitespace characters into something readable.

Comment: See string.Replace or Regex.Replace (literal or regular expression) which will work quite directly for a single \n -> "\n" (remember to slash the slash or use a string verbatim literal), but more interesting is non-printable/whitespace -> escaped.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: s = s.Replace("\r", "\"\\r\"").Replace("\n", "\"\\n\"");

Comment: newlines don't appear as `\n` in code. that's just a coder-friendly representation - a new line is a single byte, not two bytes. you'd need to do something like `s/\n/\\n/` on a per-special-char basis to translate that single newline into two literal chars.

Comment: try replacing "\n" with "\\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary and loop through the key-value pairs.

Here is an example:

```
String escp(String x) {
    Dictionary<String, String> replacements = new Dictionary<String, String>();
    replacements["\n"] = "\\n";
    replacements["\r"] = "\\r";
    replacements["\t"] = "\\t";
    foreach (var i in replacements) {
       if(x.IndexOf(i.Key) > -1)
          x = x.Replace(i.Key, i.Value);
    }
    return x;
}
```

You could use this like this:

```
String x = "This has\na new line";
Console.WriteLine(x);

String y = escp(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

And for your case, just surround `invalid.Value` with the `escp` function:

```
Console.WriteLine("Invalid character " + escp(invalid.Value));
```

Comment: I like this idea, and it actually came to mind while I was thinking the problem over, but like rashfmnb's answer it might leave me open to be blindsided, and also forces me to define a helper method. I'm surprised there's no built-in method, but I still like this answer.

Comment: Well the question comes, how do you "not" become blind-sighted, you would have to define each literal in each case to replace them.

Comment: I suppose what I was hoping for in asking the question was a built-in method. If nothing turns up for that though consider this answer accepted.

Comment: i have just wrote down an idea how to do it whether you do it by creating an extension method or doing it by just write single line in your code it all depends on how you want to use it

Comment: Want to be 100% certain you're not blindsided?  There are a limited number of escape sequence patterns.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx .  Newline and tab are by far the most popular ones.  If you're maintaining a list of invalid characters, you won't be blindsided at all - you already have a discrete list of things you're looking for.  Just have matching replacement strings for each one.

Answer (score 1):

do like this.

```
s = s.Replace("\r", "\"\\r\"").Replace("\n", "\"\\n\"");
```

or you can create the extension method

```
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
       public static int WordCount(this String str)
       {
           return str.Replace("\r", "\"\\r\"").Replace("\n", "\"\\n\"");
       }
    }
```

and call it and add as much as invalid character or string to convert it as per your requirement.

Comment: It feels like there should be a way to do this with fewer function calls, but if nothing else turns up I guess this gets the answer.

Comment: Plus, this method leaves me open to being blindsided if I fail to include something I didn't realize existed.

Answer (score 0):

[I guess you need use this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx) Replace "\n" with ""\n"".